# Find the scalar projection point with dot product

Tags: geometry

Take a look at the image bellow:

[image]

How can I find the point P, without knowing the vector B (or its end point)?
Known is:

- The vector A (start point, end point and its length)
- Angle theta

Answer (score 1):

You know the length/magnitude of vector $OP$ where $O$ is the vertex. You also know the vector $OA$. Find the unit vector in the direction of $OA$. Let us call it $e = (\cos\alpha , \sin\alpha)$. Now the direction of vector $OP$ is also known : $a = (\cos(\alpha - \theta),\sin(\alpha-\theta)) $ if $\theta $ is defined counter-clockwise.

Comment: What does "α" means in a=(cos(α−θ),sin(α−θ))?

Comment: The unit vector in direction of $OA$, namely $e$ has components $(\cos\alpha,\sin\alpha)$

Answer (score 0):

Since you know $A$, you can find the angle $A$ makes with the horizontal axis.  Call this angle $\varphi$.

Then $\varphi-\theta$ is the angle that $B$ makes with the $x$-axis.  You can now find the $x$ and $y$ coordinates using right-triangle trig.  (The hypotenuse of the triangle of interest is $\|A\|\cos\theta$.)

---

Another approach (that's more work than it's worth, but still an option) is to use the rotation matrix to make $A$ parallel to $B$.  Then compute the projection of $A$ onto this rotated vector $A$.  (This would be how I'd do it if I had a computer algebra system and only needed to solve the problem once.)

Comment: But i need P in (x,y) not the length/magnitude. Do you know how can I find [Px,Py]?

Comment: Once you know the length and magnitude, one can easily use right-triangle trig to find the $x$ and $y$ coordinates.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to find them?